# img url from base 64 data javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have base64 data and I need to convert to image src
I know the format:

```js
document.getElementById('img').setAttribute( 'src', 'data:image/png;base64, stringdatahere' );
```

But I don't know how to get my data into that string. Thanks

Comment: what tech are you using? plain html/php/asp/whatever else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the data in a variable then just

```
document.getElementById('img').setAttribute( 'src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + dataVariableName );
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how to get string data out of data object. Data object looks like this: {__type: "Bytes", base64: "jskhdbfsjdhbfjskdhbfskjhdfbsjhdb} I'm using Parse.com framework, by the way

Comment: `'data:image/png;base64,' + data.base64`

Answer (score 3):

Use string concatenation:

```
document.getElementById('img').setAttribute( 'src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + dataObject.base64 );
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how to get string data out of data object. Data object looks like this: {__type: "Bytes", base64: "jskhdbfsjdhbfjskdhbfskjhdfbsjhdb} I'm using Parse.com framework, by the way

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to get it out of that, if the object is in a variable named `dataObject`.