# Explain the base64 image display

Tags: java, html

I don't understand the items in the following code meant for displaying image

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' .  base64_encode($data)  . '" />
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Comment: [How to render base-64 string in <img> tag without knowing extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41136119/how-to-render-base-64-string-in-img-tag-without-knowing-extension), [img url from base 64 data javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670843/img-url-from-base-64-data-javascript), [Encode image file to base 64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462036/encode-image-file-to-base-64)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Base64 Encoding Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879/base64-encoding-image)

Comment: You have tagged this with java, but this looks more like PHP to me.

Answer (score 0):

When an image's link starts with a `data:`, it means the image is loaded into the page from a **MySQL Database**. The image gets directly added to the page from the Server's SQL Database and not via a picture file in the server.

Comment: That's not the complete story.  When there is a `SRC="data:..."` what it means is that the image-file, itself, is converted into what is known as **Base 64 Encoding** - _which encodes the `bytes` of the **image-file** into a subset of the **ASCII** character set_ so that they may be 'printed' into an `'.html' File`.  There are numerous Stack Overflow Answers about Base-64 Image Encodings inside of `'.html' Files.`  Just do an SO Search for "Base-64 IMG Element".  Also, the **image-file** is being loaded from some where, but that could easily be Java-Script, among other loading sources.